# How can I use mvn dependency:get with a custom repository and login information

Tags: maven

I am using a custom repository for local development (Artifactory) and that requires login information for any access. This works nicely when setting username and encrypted password in the .m2/settings.xml file and defining the repository server in the pom.xml of a project.

I am not getting it to work when using `mvn dependency:get` as the remoteRepositories property lists the server url and not the server id.

The command I currently use is

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get -DremoteRepositories=https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/repo -Dartifact=com.example.parent:parent:1`

Is it possible to put the server id value into the command line for the mvn command somehow or to look up the server url in the settings.xml file?

Comment: Take a look into the docs: `Repositories in the format id::[layout]::url or just url, separated by comma. ie. central::default::http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2,myrepo::::http://repo.acme.com,http://repo.acme2.com`

Comment: Thanks, that looks correct, but doesn't check for the user/passwort either

Comment: Of course not they should be configured in `settings.xml` file..?

Comment: they are, but its not applied to the dependency:get operation it seems (it works when I set a profile, but not without)